# Apps Script Google Direction API - arrival_stop returning ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to return `arrival_stop.name` from Google directions API in an Apps Script function. Here is my code:

```
const GOOGLEMAPS_STEPS_TRANSIT_DETAILS = (origin, destination, mode = 'transit') => {
  const { routes = [] } = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .setMode(mode)
    .getDirections();
  if (!routes.length) {
    throw new Error('No route found!');
  }

  var stepTransitDetails = routes
    .map(({ legs }) => {
      return legs.map(({ steps }) => {
        return steps.map((step) => {
          return step.transit_details.arrival_stop.name;
        });
      });
    })
    .join(' , ');

  return stepTransitDetails;
};
```

Error given:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrival_stop' of undefined (line 228).
```

Desired output is a list of stops within the transit step - for example if the step is taking the Piccadilly Line train from Leicester Square to Kings Cross the output would be the list of stations it will stop at.

I have this same code working when returning `step.html_instructions` rather than `step.transit_details.arrival_stop.name` and if I remove the `.arrival_stop.name` it returns `[object Object],,object Object],` meaning it's recognising the steps which involve transit, but adding the `.arrival_stop` gives an error.

Working based on [Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsTransitDetails)

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the data of `routes`, it seems that there are objects without including the property of `transit_details` in `step`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. If you want to retrieve `step.transit_details.arrival_stop.name`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var stepTransitDetails = routes
  .map(({ legs }) => {
    return legs.map(({ steps }) => {
      return steps.map((step) => {
        return step.transit_details.arrival_stop.name;
      });
    });
  })
  .join(' , ');
```

#### To:

```
var stepTransitDetails = routes
  .map(({ legs }) => {
    return legs.map(({ steps }) => {
      return steps.filter(({ transit_details }) => transit_details).map(({ transit_details }) => {
        return transit_details.arrival_stop.name;
      });
    });
  })
  .join(' , ');
```

- In this modification, `filter` is used for retrieving the object including `transit_details`.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)